# Resetting a spinner after removing values

Tags: java, android, spinner, default, reset

I am trying to repopulate a `Spinner` after values have been removed.

Currently the app sets up a `Spinner` with a list of string values and then as the app is used some of these values are removed from the `ArrayAdaptor`. Then at some point the `Spinner`'s list needs to be reset with the default list of values. My current code simply creates a new `ArrayAdaptor` and assigns this to the `Spinner` using the same string array resource that the `Spinner` is initially set up with:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    Static.itemList);
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Where `Static.itemlist` is an array of type `String[]`.

As it stands items are removed from the spinner but using the above code will not reset the `Spinner`'s values to the list stored in `Static.itemList`. In my mind this should work but am clearly missing something as it does not.

Full code can be found at https://github.com/Uruwolf/VO-Miner/blob/master/src/com/uruwolf/vominer/VoMinerActivity.java The method in question is from line 142 to 147 (and I know that the indentation is off, it looks fine in my editor. I am not sure why it is not right on github).

This is my first ever question on StackOverflow so please let me know if I have done something wrong.

Comment: Thinking about it https://github.com/Uruwolf/VO-Miner/blob/654b0bc40c4a1934e45bb7e13860b754a2d4594e/src/com/uruwolf/vominer/VoMinerActivity.java would be a better link for the code. (Links to a commit rather than master)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter after changing the list.

I think a better approach would be to avoid re-creating a new adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() after you've re-added the data to the main list. You don't actually need to re-create the adapter, as nothing in the adapter is changing except the the list of data that the adapter *points* to. Since the adapter just points to a list and doesn't consume/contain the list itself, if you change the referenced list, the adapter should be able to pick up the changes (when notified).

Something like this may work

**Define variables**

```
Static.itemlist ... /*This list is static. Data never changes */
List<String> myListOfStrings;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
```

**Initialize the spinner and adapter**

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     myListOfStrings);

arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

mySpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

**Refreshing the adapter**

```
myListOfStrings.clear();

myListOfStrings.addAll(Static.itemList); = /* Copy/Add the data from Static.itemList into myListOfStrings */

arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); /* Inform the adapter  we've changed items, which should force a refresh */
```